# quartz scheduler stopped schedule

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

I am using quartz 1.7 to do a heartbeat action every 5 minutes in my java program.

After one day when i look the log, the scheduling seems stoped,and stopped output any heartbeat action's log.

but other work threads are still running and output some log.

Have you ever seen this problem?

thank you.

Comment: Capture a thread-dump of the process to see if Quartz threads still exist, and if so, what they are doing.

Comment: Perhaps the trigger that was firing the job every 5 minutes reached its configured endTime ?

Answer (score 0):

Finally , find out the scheduled thread was blocked by the network I/O. 
thanks for your help.